# AX 2009 batch job got stuck in executing status

Tags: axapta, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2009

We have an issue where the batch got stuck in the executing status. Kindly let us know if some one has some suggestions on how to delete the batch job or restart the batch job.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You need to set the batch job to cancelling first, then restart your Batch AOS. When the Batch AOS comes back online, you then need to reset the status on the batch job.

Answer (score 1):

The easy one: restart your batch AOS service. This is not nice if it serves users as well!